# How to handle getResults from multiple activities?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to get results back from intents in android studio.

In my main I start an activity and use `startActivityForResult(intent, 1)`

I then use get results in mainActivity from activity 2's `setResults()`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                String name = extras.getString("FIRSTNAME");
                String Lname = extras.getString("LASTNAME");
                int ID = extras.getInt("ID");

                //TODO: Get the list fragment to newinstance with out new arraylist

                Person p = new Person(name, Lname, ID);
                people.add(p);
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, FullList.newInstance(people)).commit();
            }
```

In my fragment in activity 1 I am calling a new `startActivityForResult(i, 2)`

How do i get my main activity to grab the `setResults()`
from Activity 3?

Activity 3 is doing this:

```
Intent deleteIntent = new Intent();
deleteIntent.putExtra("FNAME", first);
deleteIntent.putExtra("LNAME", last);
deleteIntent.putExtra("ID", num);
setResult(RESULT_OK, deleteIntent);
finish();
```

I am trying to have my main activity call `if (requestCode == 2)`

But it works to no avail.

Here is the all the onActivityResult for reference:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                String name = extras.getString("FIRSTNAME");
                String Lname = extras.getString("LASTNAME");
                int ID = extras.getInt("ID");

                //TODO: Get the list fragment to newinstance with out new arraylist

                Person p = new Person(name, Lname, ID);
                people.add(p);

                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, FullList.newInstance(people)).commit();
            }

            // NOW SEEING IF THE DETAILS SCREEN PASSED BACK RESULTS

        } else if (requestCode == 2) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                if (extras != null) {
                    String name = extras.getString("FNAME");
                    String Lname = extras.getString("LNAME");
                    int ID = extras.getInt("ID");

                    Person p = new Person(name, Lname, ID);
                    // Delete happens here //
                    if (people.contains(p)) {
                        people.remove(p);
                        // If empty show blank frag, if not, update list //
                        if (people.isEmpty()) {
                            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, BlankList.newInstance());
                        } else {
                            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, FullList.newInstance(people)).commit();
                        }

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "DIDNT RECEIVE SAME INFO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // END ELSE CHECK
    }
}
```

Here is the code that is calling the `startActivityForResult()` in the Fragment on activity 1.

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    //super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    ArrayList<Person> people = (ArrayList<Person>) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_People);

    if (people != null && position != -1) {
        Person listPerson = people.get(position);
        Intent i = new Intent("OPENDETAILS");
        i.putExtra("NAME", listPerson.name);
        i.putExtra("LASTNAME", listPerson.lName);
        i.putExtra("ID", listPerson.ID);
        startActivityForResult(i, 2);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "EMPTY LIST ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code containing `if (requestCode == 2)` because that is correct

Comment: Just put up the rest here!

Comment: Does `Person` implement Comparable or have the equals method implemented? Otherwise `if (people.contains(p)) {` will not work

Comment: people is an array list of type Person. I am checking to make sure it contains this object.

Comment: Yes, but I don't think you understand how the `contains` method operates. How does know *how to compare* two `Person` objects?

Comment: Okay I am putting this next update, because solution seemed to work, but on checking further it has not.

Comment: Just do `else if (requestCode == 2) { Log.d("result", "here?"); }`. Your code probably works fine. It is the content of that else-if statement that does not

Comment: Just now checking. It seems to not even be hitting my onActivityResult(). When I click my button to call that activity 3 setResult() it isnt getting back to Mains call.

Comment: Well, one way to debug is just drop random `Log.d` statements everywhere you think the code should run, then trace down the problem. What you have looks correct, as far as your overall question is concerned.

Comment: Okay let me do  a quick debug. It is telling me that on finish() of that intent that the frame is not available. Is it looking for activity 2?  Because I call startActivityForResult() in the second activity, not main!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a little unclear what you're trying to do, but it sounds like:

1. Activity1 starts Activity2 for result
2. Activity2 starts Activity3 for result
3. Activity3 returns a result
4. Activity1 is expected receive Activity3's result.

If I got that right then the key element that seems to be missing here is that you are expecting Activity1 to get a result from Activity3 even though it was Activity2 that started it for result.  In this case you should implement `onActivityResult` in Activity2, handle the results coming back from Activity3 and set them as Activity2's results to pass back to Activity1 and then finish; An activity will only receive results from activities it directly starts via `startActivityForResult`.

Comment: Let me try this real quick!  This is the way I have it set up, and I was wondering if that is how it has to work in order for it to get this info!

Comment: could I make activity 2 implement an interface that activity 1 can override that calls startActivityForResult() on Activity 3?

Comment: Nope there's a pretty hardcore serialization boundary between activities that prevents doing this kind of thing in an OO way. (ActivityX shouldnt be able to directly reference an instance of ActivityY)  You could use broadcast events if you wanted, but it wouldn't be any better than an activity result IMO.

Comment: Okay thank you for not making me wast my time on that. I guess I will try to make activity 2 get all the results here. Activity one is containing a list fragment, and the fragment is the one calling the startActivityForResults()

Comment: one thing you can do to make your life a little easier is to put all your results into a Bundle and then put the bundle into the intent, instead of directly into the intent, that way in Activity2 all you have to do is grab that bundle out of the extras and put that single item into it's result.

Comment: So I believe my actual issue here is that this fragment wants to call for results but isnt there to receive them? I changed saying it was activity 2 in my post to fix the confusion, I was saying activity because the screen being filled. Dumb mistake there.

Comment: so you're using a fragment instead of an activity?  the same basic principle applies.  Fragments can override onActivityResult and do the above just like Activities.  Either way, the entity that calls startActivityForResult is the entity whose onActivityResult method will be invoked when the activity finishes.  I know it seems reasonable that because the fragment exists within Activity1 that Activity1 would get the result, but it wont :)

Comment: something that just occurred to me that you can try.. From inside your Fragment, instead of calling `startActivityForResult` call `getActivity().startActivityForResult` instead.  This should use the Activity holding the fragment (Activity1) as the recipient for the result, instead of the fragment.

Answer (score 2):

Use different code to launch different activities,
such as

```
startActivtityForResult(new Intent(this,Person1.class),1);
startActivtityForResult(new Intent(this,Person2.class),2);
startActivtityForResult(new Intent(this,Person3.class),3);
```

then on activityresult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (resultCode) {

        case 1:
             //implement your code here
            break;

        case 2:
             //implement your code here
            break;

        case 3:
              //implement your code here
            break;
    }
}
```

then set Retrun result in these classes

Person1.class

```
return_intent.putExtra("result", 1);
setResult(1, return_intent);
```

Person2.class

```
Person1.class

return_intent.putExtra("result", 2);
setResult(2, return_intent);
```

Person3.class

```
Person1.class

return_intent.putExtra("result", 3);
setResult(3, return_intent);
```

Comment: you want to grab the results from Activity 3, and your are returning the intent not the result code, return the result code also.